# Set text color for the indicator of TabHost, when it's selected

Tags: android, android-tabhost, indicator

how can I change text color of the indicator, when the tab is selected. I want to have a difference between 2 tabs.
Thanks

[image: TabHost]

[I want it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cND3D.png)

Comment: please provide some codes so we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        View view = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
        if ( view != null ) {

            // get title text view
            TextView textView = (TextView)view. findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

    }
    title.setTextColor(Color.RED); 
}
```

Comment: How can I add TextView tab_title into the TabWidget?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [documentation](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-change-tab-bar-background-color/), inside `onCreate()` method to define initial background color for the selected and unselected tab.

```
for(int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();  i++) {
       tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));
}
   tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));
```

Implement the `OnTabChangeListener` to current activity and then override the `onTabChanged()` method. In that method, write the below code to define color for selected tab and unselected tab.

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++){
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8A4117"));
    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C35817"));
}
```

**Update**

Change you tab text color:

- Via xml file:

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      app:tabTextColor="@color/your_color"
      app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/your_color"/>
  ```
- Via code:

  ```
  tabLayout.setTabTextColors(
      ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_unselected_tab_text_color),
      ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_selected_tab_text_color)
  );
  ```

Comment: No. I want to change the text color, not the tab color. But I appreciate on your help. Do you know how to change the text color of the indicator, when I select a tab?